# Grouping comments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of comment objects. Each comment has a primary_key, comment_text, date_posted, and thread_id. The thread_id refers to the primary_key of the parent comment.

Given the following three comments

```
var comments = [
    {content: "parent comment", primary_key: 1, date_posted: 12/10/14, thread_id: null},
    {content: "another parent comment", primary_key: 2, date_posted: 12/11/14, thread_id: null},
    {content: "reply", primary_key: 3, date_posted: 12/11/14, thread_id: 1}
]
```

How can I return an array of sorted comments where all replies to parent comments will follow the parent comment (preferably sorted by date)?

I've been able to break out replies using

```
_.filter(comments, function(comment) { return comment.thread })
```

but am struggling to reconcile them with the comments

desired output would be

```
[
    {content: "parent comment", primary_key: 1, date_posted: 12/10/14, thread_id: null},
    {content: "reply", primary_key: 3, date_posted: 12/11/14, thread_id: 1},
    {content: "another parent comment", primary_key: 2, date_posted: 12/11/14, thread_id: null}
]
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2ewaxgdu/

Comment: Think about what you're asking. If you have `[1,2,3,4,5]` and 2 is the parent of 5, you're wanting to sort it as `[1,2,5,3,4]`, but that could be interpreted as 1 is the parent of 2, which is the parent of 5, which is the parent of 3, which...

Comment: fiddle please? And put up expected output you want

Comment: @JonathanM I don't think OP wants to do a perfectly-reconstructable ordering; just a comment list where no reply comes before its parent.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Maybe an layered object structure is best.

Comment: Typo in your example: `[` ... `]` missing around the `comments` objects.

Comment: @hbk35 fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2ewaxgdu/

Comment: @JonathanM I want to be able to iterate over a list of comments and have all replies be children of their parent comment

Comment: can you add parent_id? Sorry, I realised after I wrote the comment that the thread id must be that

Comment: I think the best result would be a main object with an array of comment objects and inside that would be the array of comment objects:

Comment: {comments: [{'content': 'lskjdlksdj', replies: [{}], [{}] }]}